# OperationalError: no such column: api_patients.medStaff_id

Tags: django

I am simply trying to define a foreign key but every time, I try to access my table i get an error message as follow:

```
OperationalError: no such column: api_patients.medStaff_id
```

Here is how i define my 2 tables:

```
MED_STAFF_ROLES = (('gp', 'General Practitien'),
              ('nurse', 'Nurse'),
              ('gs', 'General Sergeon'))

class medStaff(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    dob = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    role = MultiSelectField(choices=MED_STAFF_ROLES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class patients(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    dob = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    medStaff = models.OneToOneField(medStaff, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I have run migrate and makemigrations but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: yes i did, multiple times ...

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: it complie fine, no errors no nothing it just works, the error only appears when i try to access my tables

Comment: You're going to need to give more information. Where are you running this code? What is the actual output from migrate?

Comment: the actual output is this: 
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: And i dont understand what do you mean by "where do i run this code"

Comment: I am accessing my tables using this http://192.168.1.5:8000/admin/api/patients/ this is when i get the error however if i try to access http://192.168.1.5:8000/admin/api/medStaff it works fine